# How to check if linked server is running within a function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I know that there is a way to check if the linked server is running.
I wanna know if there is a way to check it inside a function
I wrote this code:

```
  create function dbo.Ck_DB_Stat
(@servername nvarchar (20))
returns bit
AS
BEGIN

    declare @srvr nvarchar(128), @retval int, @res nvarchar (10)

    declare @ck bit
    set @srvr = @servername;
    begin try
        exec @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @srvr;
        set @ck = 1
    end try

    begin catch
        set @retval = sign(@@error);
    end catch;

    if @retval <> 0
        set @ck = 0
    return @ck
END
```

Comment: You can't execute a stored proc inside a function.

Comment: In `SQL CLR` function you are able to execute dynamic SQL statement, so I guess it will be `OK` to execute other procedures as well.